# Vagrant SSH No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am trying to import a mysql db into my freshly created local vagrant ubuntu VM on windows 10.
But when I SSH in, I cannot identify where I am. Nor can I find the .sql Which I kopied in the VM directory. 
In perspection to my windows path I have no idea where I am when I SSH in nor where I have to put the file I am trying to use.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**ERROR:**
No such file or directory

**IDE Terminal:**

```
PS C:\comp\Projecte\VagrantVM\oxvm_eshop> vagrant ssh
vagrant@oxideshop:~$ ls -a
    .  ..  .ansible  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .composer  .my.cnf  .mysql_history  .profile  .ssh
    vagrant@oxideshop:~$ mysql -u oxid -p oxid <C:\comp\Projecte\VagrantVM\oxvm_eshop\oxideshop\2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql
    -bash: C:compProjecteVagrantVMoxvm_eshopoxideshop2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql: No such file or directory
    vagrant@oxideshop:~$ mysql -u oxid -p oxid <C:/comp/Projecte/VagrantVM/oxvm_eshop/oxideshop/2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql
    -bash: C:/comp/Projecte/VagrantVM/oxvm_eshop/oxideshop/2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql: No such file or directory
    vagrant@oxideshop:~$ mysql -u oxid -p oxid </oxideshop/2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql
    -bash: /oxideshop/2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql: No such file or directory
    vagrant@oxideshop:~$ mysql -u oxid -p oxid <2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql
    -bash: 2018_09_28_s_28042_db_0.sql: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls /vagrant` (which is where the Vagrant directory is "mounted" when inside the VM)? (This is described in detail in the Vagrant documentation, actually... when you are SSH'ed in, you are in `/home/vagrant`, the Vagrant user's home directory. The host OS directory where the `Vagrantfile` is located is available at `/vagrant`, and you can edit your `Vagrantfile` to, basically, mount any host directory at any VM location you want.)

Comment: I see the file. So even so, I see vagrant@oxideshop I have to cd /vagrant to go in the folder oxideshop. This seems strange, but ok, thanks

Comment: `vagrant@oxideshop` means your user is `vagrant`, and _your hostname is `oxideshop`_. This isn't referring to your current directory. (Which you can check with `pwd`.) The directory is called `oxideshop` _on the host OS_... but the VM does not "see" the host OS file system. It just "sees" the directory the `Vagrantfile` resides in, which by convention is mounted as `/vagrant` inside the VM.

Comment: ok, thanks for the walk through